# Breaking Fast .. unintentionally? Or intentionally?

Tags: ramadan, sawm

So I was in Switzerland during the entire month of Ramadan. As  you know, Switzerland has a very interchangeable weather and I have an autoimmune disease .. meaning my immune system can crash whenever weather changes. I was in an internship so I was sick during the entire month of Ramadan. One day I decided to climb a mountain and while the sun was rising I decided not to fast because a) I considered it "travelling", b) I thought I was excused since I'm an Egyptian in Switzerland so I am not in my own country and the hours of fasting were 18 hours and a half, and c) I was still sick.

Does this mean I broke my fast on purpose? What do I do to make up for it? I can't fast for two months in a row, Ramadan is coming up

Answer (score 2):

No as far as I can tell, this does not mean you broke your fast on purpose, and all you have to do is fast the number of days you did not do (outside of Ramadan).  My answer is based on one assumption, if I am incorrect (which you have to judge for yourself) then my answer does not apply to you.  My assumption is:

- You left your country but with the intention of going back and not staying in switzerland

As a traveler is on travel even if he stays long in a place as long as he intends to go back to his own country after he has fulfilled his matter of traveling.  Fasting while traveling may fall into a few categories, among which is the choice between fasting and breaking fast, and although fasting maybe better and more liked you have the choice.

As for fasting in your condition (illness), if the fast further harms you should not fast, for this you must/or can consult a trustworthy doctor (Muslim or non-Muslim) and they can tell you their judgement.

And Allah knows best, and I ask Him for forgiveness of any mistakes I made.

For further information [see this(Arabic)](http://www.ibnothaimeen.com/all/books/printer_16605.shtml)

---

Also it should be noted, that fasting two months is not the only options for the kafarah of purposely breaking fast, there are two others:

- Freeing a slave
- Feeding sixty poor persons

[Source](https://sunnah.com/bukhari:6821)

Comment: How is freeing a slave an option today?

Answer (score 1):

Breaking a fast means this:

You fasting from the beginning of the day, then because of something you break it unintentionally Or intentionally.

If it is unintentionally, your fasting is true and you can continue it until the end of the day.

But if it is intentionally, you have to fast 60 days instead of one day fast breaking.

But when you are in a travel (below ten days in a specific city) or you are sick, You can not fast. You can fast if you want to stay in a city more than ten days and you are not sick.

But the most important thing is you have to fast in other months instead of the Ramadan you lost.

I bring you an example, When a person is sick and cannot suffer 18 hours without water and gonna be ill, So if he can suffer 10 hours without water, he can not pay Kaffarah and must 
fast in other months which the day light is 10 hours and less.

Kaffarah is just for a person who can not suffer thirst or hunger at all because of a sickness.

Comment: I just have a note; I was sick however I was able to climb a mountain.. that is why i dont know if im excused or not

Comment: I myself can climb the mountain but can't fast. My body can not suffer shortage  of water and after fasting I have to go to the hospital. So doctors forbid me to fast. If Your body immune system getting week by fasting you can not fast. Or maybe by whether if you had to use medicine. But if you feel bad and it is not a dangerous situation you can not avoid fasting.